# Refinement Panel - SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am facing problems with Refinement Panel in **SharePoint 2010**.

**Please find below the issue:**
Suppose we have Following refinement Custom Values as - Custom1, Custom2, Custom3, Custom4, Custom5. And then suppose Custom1-5 have things coming from Managed Properties.

I have uploaded adequate number of documents into the system. Now when I click on one of the values under Custom1 then filtering is done properly...and it shows Custom2, Custom3 if there are any document. I click on values under Custom2 and I could further drill down and get more specific results. All this is default functionality by SharePoint. I have not changed anything here.

But sometimes SharePoint is behaving strangely. If I click on one of the values under Custom3 (or Custom4, Custom5)...then all other filter options are gone. Only Custom3 and the value I clicked to select are shown. I know that the documents in this particular category have Managed Properties which exists under Custom1 and Custom2, yet those are not seen.

My client is after me saying that this is a bug, can anyone help me regarding the same. Am I doing something wrong is this is BUG/FEATURE by SharePoint. If it is a bug or feature please do share with me some document by Microsoft or others mentioning the same. I Googled a lot but could only find ways to use Managed Property etc with Refinement Panel.

Thanks. 
Nitin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its simple...just change the Threshold Value from 5 to 1. I did not know and wasted so much time running around. I hope this question may save some time for someone else.